# Better VBA way to compress list

Tags: excel, vba

Have a few questions about the following code that compressed and reformats a list.

1. I set variable `endIndicator` as a temporary marker for the end of the list. Would it be better to just continually check for the current end of the list via my `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1`?
2. I tried a `With ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset)` statement  in the delete loop which gives me a

   > run time error 424 Object Required

   on the second iteration of the loop. I gather this has to do with the destruction of the previous row. Is there an appropriate `With` statement to use for this loop?
3. Similarly, I tried a `With ActiveCell.EntireColumn` for the last three statements and get the same result. I assume for the same reason. Is there an appropriate solution?

Here's the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Condense1()    
'Purpose : Condense list by removing unwanted rows    
'Requires: Column B row verbiage    
'          Column A row blank for unwanted row    
'Returns : Single compressed column of values wanted    

    Dim endIndicator As String
    Dim rowOffset As Long

    Worksheets(1).Activate          'Select Sheet
    Range("A1").Select              'Set offset base

    endIndicator = "zzzendozx"      'Assign unique value unlikely to be duplicated
                                    'Find last used row
    rowOffset = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count _
        + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1
                                    'Temporarily mark next row as loop terminator
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset, 0).Value = endIndicator

    rowOffset = 0                   'Reset offset pointer

                                    'For each row from top to loop terminator
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset).Value <> endIndicator
                                    ' Delete rows whose column "A" is empty
        If Len(ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset).Value) < 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            rowOffset = rowOffset + 1   'Otherwise prepare to look at next row
        End If
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset).EntireRow.Delete   'Remove loop terminator row
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete                  'Remove Column A
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Font.Size = 14          'Set Font
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit                 'Set optimum column width

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to read up on how to avoid Select/ActiveCell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Could you try to describe in 1-2 sentences what exactly you are trying to achieve with your code? Ideally provide some data (eg. picture of data) with input and expected result. Makes it a bit easier to comprehend

Comment: Rawplus: I do not know how to add a picture. Cells A3 A5 A6 and A8 contain a letter "x". Cells B1 B2 and B4 contain literal "ignore", Cells B3 B5 and B6 contain literal "Show" Cell B8 contains "After skipped row". All other cells blank or unused. When done, I expect a single column with  A1 A2 and  A3  as "Show" and A4 as "After skipped row"

Comment: SJR Reading up on that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help:

```
Sub Kompressor()
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nFirstRow As Long, i As Long
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row

    For i = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        With Cells(i, 1)
            If .Value = "" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note we run the loop **backwards**.
The code will run slightly faster if we delete only one time.

Comment: Thank you. works nicely. Note that r is not defined in you code. I set it as Range and it worked.